# how do I move on to the next proxy without using a proxy another thread has used? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, proxy

I'm trying to run a python program that involves threads and a proxy list but not all these proxies might work. If a proxy failure happens how do I move on to the next proxy without using a proxy another thread has used?

My code:

```
from threading import Thread 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def run_session(accounts,proxy):
    
    firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "httpProxy": proxy,
        "sslProxy": proxy
    }

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)

    driver.get('example')

accounts = [
    {
    'test_name':'Test_1',
    'name':'NA',
    },
    {
    'test_name':'Test_2',
    'name':'NA',
    },
    {
    'test_name':'Test_3',
    'name':'NA',
    }]

perfect_proxies_list = [62.205.169.74:53281,66.94.97.238:443,178.217.172.206:55443,171.97.54.242:55443,119.76.142.153:8080]

for act, proxy in zip(accounts, perfect_proxies_list):
    Thread(target=run_session, args=(act,proxy)).start()
```

Comment: You need to provide a list of spares proxies (as you have used all of them when setting up the threads in the for loop, leaving none behind for the purpose of moving onto the next proxy) and track which thread has failed with what proxy and try again with a new proxy from the list of spares.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.